# Mediawiki category entries on pages render as [[index.php?title=Category:Fubar]] and not as entered [[Category:Fubar]]

Tags: mediawiki

Mediawiki page entries are converting Category text on pages such as [[Category:Fubar]]
to include the URL such as: [[index.php?title=Category:Fubar]]

Happens with visual or code editor. Using Mediawiki 1.40

It may have something to do with the rewrite rules but I don't want to mess with that without knowing what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to this. Add to localsettings.php:

```
$wgUsePathInfo= true;
```